# WPF how can i get a control from another control inside a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, controls

I'm currently trying to get a `DataGrid` control in WPF to send it as `CommandParameter`.

The structure looks like that:

Main XAML:

```
<Usercontrol>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"/>
    <view:AnotherUsercontrol/>
</Usercontrol>
```

AnotherUsercontrol XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid}" 
            Content="Export"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It does not work. The command works, but I do not get the parameter. I tried with a propdp in the code behind of `AnotherUsercontrol.cs` but same result:

Main XAML:

```
<Usercontrol>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"/>
    <view:AnotherUsercontrol DataGrid="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
</Usercontrol>
```

AnotherUsercontrol XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}
            CommandParameter="{Binding DataGrid}" 
            Content="Export"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is that I need to use the control `View:AnotherUsercontrol` because its used in all my views (a lot of them).

Some idea about how could that work?

Greetings

PD: I'm using MVVM, and yes, I need to send the control like a parameter because I'm using Infragistics, and they use the `DataPresenter` of the `XamDataGrid` to export it in Excel format.

Comment: In order to bind to its own properties, the XAML of a UserControl should use RelativeSource Bindings, like `CommandParameter="{Binding DataGrid, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: Ty so much for your answer. It works if later in code behind i find the XamDataGrid child of the UserControl. But, is it not too much expensive? there is a way to send just the XamDataGrid and not all the UserControl? Greetings

Comment: You mean if it makes sense to have that DataGrid property in the first place? No idea. You would typically not pass a control as command parameter at all, but just some appropriate data item.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. It work fine at the moment, but you are right, it is not working as a MVVM aproach should do. In this case it is an exception, since it is a requirement to use the entire control as a parameter to export its structure to an excel file.